# Clicking on hyperlink with partial href on Internet Explorer using vba

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to create a script to click on a link of which I can provide a partial link. It would be great if someone may please advise how I can do this

```
<a href="website/report/download.json?refId=3e49762e-8edc-47c2-a282-11ee3c64e85a&amp;reportType=xlsx&amp;fileName=GeneralExtract.xlsx&amp;obo>GeneralExtract.xlsx</a>


Set i = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idoc = i.document
Set eles6 = idoc.getElementsByTagName("a")


For Each ele6 In eles6
If ele6.href = "fileName=GeneralExtract" Then
    ele6.Click
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the querySelector method and the `[attribute^=value]` [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), it will selects every  element whose href attribute value begins with special value.

Sample code as below (it will select the a tag whose href attribute value begins with `website/report/download.json`):

```
Public Sub ClickTest()

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "<the website url>"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ie.Document.querySelector("a[href^='website/report/download.json']").Click

    End With
End Sub
```

Besides, you could also find the  tag use the getelementsbytagname method, then using for statement to loop through the result, and according to the innerText property to find the special link. Finally, click it.

**Edit**

You could check the following code:

```
Public Sub ClickTest()

    Dim ie As Object    
    Dim itemlist As Object  'Define a object to store the a tag list.

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "<the website url>"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        'ie.Document.querySelector("a[href^='website/report/download.json']").Click

        Set itemlist = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

        'Debug.Print itemlist.Length  ' check the count of a tag

        If Len(itemlist) > 0 Then
            'using For Each statement to loopthough the a tag list.
            For Each Item In itemlist
                'Debug.Print Item.innerText  ' check the value
                'If the value is "GeneralExtract.xlsx", click the link and exit the for statement.
                If Item.innerText Like "GeneralExtract.xlsx" Then
                    Item.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Item
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, can you please advise how can I use innerText for href. I tried multiple times but was not able to correctly write it

Comment: @Hanit Singh Saluja, you could check the above code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks alot it works and has resolved my problem:)