# Trying to click in a button using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, button, click

Newbie here, trying to click in a button. I need to opne a browser, navigate to a site, fill in some fields and click in a button. Does not work! This codes are opening the IE, navigating, but not clicking in the button...

Im using this codes below

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "My site"
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("My button ID > a").Click

        Stop
    End With
End Sub

OR THIS ONE

Sub Test2Felipe()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "My site"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("My button ID > a").Click

        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally we could use the **getElementById**, **getElementsByClassName** method or **getElementsByName** method to access the elements from web page, according to your website html resource, I suggest you could use the following code to access the related elements and click the button:

```
Public Sub ClickTest()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://fakepath/Login"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        'find the textbox and fill value
        ie.Document.getElementById("Usuario").Value = "test"
        ie.Document.getElementById("Senha").Value = "test"
        
        'Click the button
        ie.Document.getElementsByName("ActionButton")(0).Click  
         
    End With
End Sub
```

More detail information, please check the following links:

[Common VBA Methods & Properties used in web automation](http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/)

[Clicking on hyperlink with partial href on Internet Explorer using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756188/clicking-on-hyperlink-with-partial-href-on-internet-explorer-using-vba/59773583#59773583)

**Edit**:

Try close all the explorer instances through 'Task manager', then use internet explorer at a medium integrity level, code as below

```
Public Sub ClickTest()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorerMedium
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://fakepath/Login"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        'find the textbox and fill value
        ie.Document.getElementById("Usuario").Value = "test"
        ie.Document.getElementById("Senha").Value = "test"

        'Click the button
        ie.Document.getElementsByName("ActionButton")(0).Click

    End With
End Sub
```

[Note] Please remember to add references for Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: Error in "While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4" error mesage: The Busy method from <IWebBroswer2> failed"...

Comment: I solve this error doing this "Do Until ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop"

Comment: Now, the error is in this line "ie.Document.getElementById("Usuario").Value = "test"" error message: the method "document" from object "IWebBroswer2" failed"

Comment: @Vaz, Try to close all the explorer instances through 'Task manager', then use internet explorer at a medium integrity level, please refer to the above edited code.

Comment: WORKS FINE! **\0/\0/** I'm using this method to click in the other buttons in the page, after logging in. But, how can I get this type of button? **<A class="ctl00_Menu_1 CWIMenuStaticMenuItemStyle ctl00_Menu_3 ctl00_Menu_13 CWIMenuStaticHoverStyle" style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; FONT-SIZE: 1em; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; MARGIN-LEFT: 16px" href="/URS/Pages/Cadastros/cadRelatorioTemplate.aspx" hoverHyperLinkClass="ctl00_Menu_13 CWIMenuStaticHoverStyle">Relatórios</A>**

Comment: Since this hyperlink contains the class property, you could use the getElementsByClassName() method to find the hyperlink according to the class name property, then find the specific hyperlink based on the array index. More detail information about using this method, please check [this link](http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/). Besides, you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756188/) to find the hyperlink use the querySelector method and the [attribute^=value] CSS selector.

Comment: Ive tried (**ie.Document.querySelector("a[href='/URS/Pages/Cadastros/cadRelatorioTemplate.aspx']").Click**) or (**ie.Document.querySelector("a.ctl00_Menu_1 CWIMenuStaticMenuItemStyle ctl00_Menu_3 CWIMenuStaticSelectedStyle ctl00_Menu_9[href^='/URS/Pages/Cadastros/cadRelatorioTemplate.aspx']").Click**) but none of them worked.

Comment: You could find the hyperlink using the getElementsByClassName() method, code as below: `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("ctl00_Menu_1 CWIMenuStaticMenuItemStyle ctl00_Menu_3 ctl00_Menu_13 CWIMenuStaticHoverStyle")(0).Click
`,  Or using the querySelector method, code like this: `ie.Document.querySelector("a[href^='/URS/Pages/Cadastros/cadRelatorioTemplate.aspx']").Click`. Besides, please check the html resource, make sure there is not an iframe tag outside the hyperlink, if it contains the iframe tag, we need to find the iframe tag first, then find the hyperlink.